# Display Series of Images on each View in iCaorusel

Tags: ios, icarousel

I have the following implementation, which displays each single image on each view in the carousel. The following code works and functional.

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view{

    if (view == nil){
        view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200 , 200)];
        ((UIImageView *)view).image = [self.items objectAtIndex:index];
        view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
        [view.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    }
    return view;
}
```

However, I would like to show a series of images(animation) on each view. Is that possible? I have three views- walking, biking and driving. Here is one of my animation series of image implementation. However, I could not able to find a way to fit into iCarousel.

```
-(void)walkingAnimation
{
    NSInteger imagesCount = 22;
    NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //iterate through each images
    for (int i = 0;
         i <= imagesCount; i++) {
        [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Walking-%d", i]]];
    }

    avatarImage.animationImages = images;
    avatarImage.animationDuration = 1.5;
    [self.view addSubview:avatarImage];
    [avatarImage startAnimating];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIImageView has an animatedImage property. Assign it an array of images, and they should result in the effect you want.